# Why does my Startup Security Utility window look different?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, security

I am trying to check the security of my Mac Mini before installing Windows with bootcamp.

According to [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198), the window should look like this:

[image]

However mine looks like this:

[image]

Why is that and how can I make sure I have the right settings before installing windows?

Mac Mini mid 2011 with High Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [linked support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198) only addresses Macs with a T2 security chip.

Your MacMini from 2011 does not have this chip.

Keep in mind that [BootCamp will not able to install Windows 10 on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468).

Comment: Ah dang. Ok thanks. Maybe I’ll try Windows XP

Comment: Windows 7 can be ok. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to Macs with the T2 security chip. Mac Mini computers did not include T2 security chips until the 2018 model. See: [Mac models with the Apple T2 Security Chip](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862).

You can use the Boot Camp Assistant include with High Sierra to install [32 bit or 64 bit Windows 7](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016) or [64 bit Windows 8/8.1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201457). According to [this article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/), you should still be able to upgrade to Windows 10 for free.

If you choose to directly install Windows 10, then here are some previous questions where Windows 10 was successfully installed on 2011 Macs.

[When trying to install Windows 10 on 2011 iMac keep getting error 0x8007000D windows cannot open the required file D:\sources\install.wim](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391501/when-trying-to-install-windows-10-on-2011-imac-keep-getting-error-0x8007000d-win)

[How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant)

[How to install Windows 10 on unsupported Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222007/how-to-install-windows-10-on-unsupported-mac)

Comment: Thanks the question was answered and the answer was accepted. I might try XP. Thanks

Comment: From my memory, XP needed to have SP 2 included on the DVD. Anyway, according to [everyman.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/index-macmini.html), XP is not available for your model. In other words, the Windows Support Software provided by Apple probably will not be compatible with XP.

Comment: Any idea what windows version 8 can run on my machine either with bootcamp or parallels?

Comment: You should be able to download the [latest Windows 8.1 from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO). I believe you can install using a Windows 8 or 8.1 product key. Although my information may be out of date. I have never used Parallels. I use VMware Fusion Player and VirtualBox because they are free products.

Comment: Thanks David I will try that. Do I buy the product key on a different page?

Comment: I think Microsoft no longer sells Windows 8.1 product keys. You would have to buy one from some other seller. I searched the internet and there does not seem to be a shortage of sellers. I would suggest first installing Windows 10 without a product key just to test the performance. Microsoft will allow this for a short time before requiring a product key.